# Sharepoint 365 the file has been modified [...]

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow, concurrency

I have a simple document content type that has some fields.
I have also attached a simple approval workflow to this content type.
The workflow automatically start when a new item is created on the document library.

However some times, very often, after having uploaded the file and filled the form, I get an error saying that `the document has been modified by (user that is making the upload) on <<date>>`. This error will always save the document in the library but I need to reopen it and save it again because my modifications are lost. The file remains in checked out state.

This is a screen showing the error (i am sorry that s in italian)

[image]

I am seeing that the error is reported with the timezone of the server while the item is saved correctly with the site collection and user timezone.

I suspect that this modification is related to the fact that the workflow starts immediately and modify the item. Could this be a cause? How do I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have also been having this issue for several months now. I just found the answer elsewhere on Stack Exchange at it worked! Here is the link: [Cannot save document properties with workflow enabled](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130274/cannot-save-document-properties-with-workflow-enabled)